# Expose a (custom) header in a single endpoint while other headers are exposed in the CORS policy

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an endpoint like this:

```cs
[HttpGet("{hardwareId}/calculations/")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CalculationResult>> GetCalculations(string hardwareId)
{
    // results will be null if the calculations are not done yet
    List<CalculationResult> results = await FindCalculationResults(hardwareId);

    if (results != null)
    {
        return result.Networks;
    }
    else
    {
        var resultUri = BuildResultUri(hardwareId);
        Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.AccessControlExposeHeaders, HeaderNames.Location);
        return Accepted(resultUri);
    }
}
```

This worked as expected with the CORS policy we had at that time which did not have any exposed headers. The `Location` header is correctly listed in the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`.

Recently, we changed our CORS policy and added the `Content-Disposition` header to the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`:

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins(corsConfiguration.Origins);
        builder.WithMethods(corsConfiguration.Methods);
        builder.AllowAnyHeader();
        builder.AllowCredentials();

        //  added recently -> now, although it is explicitly set, the 'Location'
        // header from the 'GetCalculations'-endpoint is no longer exposed
        builder.WithExposedHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition); 
    });
});
```

The `Content-Disposition` is now exposed in all requests that use the default CORS policy. However, the 'Location' header in the `GetCalculations` endpoint is no longer exposed. It seems that the CORS policy completely overwrites the headers that I have exposed manually. Adding the 'Location' header with `.WithExposedHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, HeaderNames.Location)` works but exposes the 'Location' header in all requests which is not what I want.

How can I expose the `Location` header in a single Endpoint while having a CORS policy that sets other `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` headers?

Comment: Hi @Thomas D. , what if you try `builder.WithExposedHeaders(new string[] { HeaderNames.ContentDisposition,HeaderNames.Location });` ?

Comment: yes, this works and is the solution I am currently using. However, this would expose the `Location` header in every request that uses this CORS policy which is not what I'd want to do. I'd like to expose that header specifically in only a single endpoint while still using the same CORS policy.